# Is a vert.x even bus address uni-directional?

Tags: vert.x

Two verticles need to send and receive data between them. Is it necessary to have two event bus addresses one for each direction. Or is it possible to have a single vert.x event bus address and send/receive both on the same address.

Comment: This is possible if you only need to reply to a message. For example Verticle A -> send data to B -> B process data -> B sends response back to A. Also I don't understand about addresses on each direction. If you want to have Verticles to receive data they only need one address. You don't need address for one Verticle for both send and receive.

Comment: Let's say there are verticles A and B. A  consumes Evenbus address "myQue". It also sends on the address "myQue".  Verticle B also does the same. So A sends Messages to B on the event bus address C. And B uses the same event bus address "myQue" to send data to A. Is this possible ? This is not a request/reply scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In vert.x, when you send a message through a eventBus, you can register a replayHandler to receive reply message.

```
<T> EventBus send(String address,
                  Object message,
                  Handler<AsyncResult<Message<T>>> replyHandler)
```

[vert.x send with replyHandler](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#send-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-io.vertx.core.Handler-)

Answer (score 0):

EventBus is unidirectional.

If you need to send independent messages from `A->B` and from `B->A`, you'll have to register two addresses.

I would still recommend against that, since circular dependencies are error prone. Essentially, that's a common recipe for a deadlock. A is waiting for a message from B, while B is waiting for a message from A.

What usually is done in such cases is introducing a broker. That broker will receive all messages, and decided where this messages goes from here. So, instead of A and B holding each an EventBus address, they'll use reply mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I have a need to send independent mesages from A to B and from B to A. Is there any other options than having two different addresses as circular dependencies might be an issue. Also can you kindly explain how a circular dependency might occur.